# How to use Grails services in a helper class

Tags: grails, grails-services

I have a service created  in `Grails 2.4` services section. In controller, it is using dependency injection and it is automatically initialized. I want to use the same service say `ClassifiedService` from a custom helper class which is defined in `src/groovy` folder.

**Question 1**: Should I directly call the service as below:

```
ClassifiedService classifiedService = new ClassifiedService()
```

If I try to use the dependency injection of Grails, like below, the object is always null.

```
def classifiedService
```

**Question 2**: It is recommended to create an interface for the Service method and use it and initialize it with the actual class?

Answer (score 2):

You can add you helper class to `conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
import foo.bar.MyHelperClass

beans = {
   myHelperClass(MyHelperClass)
}
```

This creates a bean named `myHelperClass` with class `MyHelperClass`. All fields inside this bean are autowired (dependency injection happens automatically).

After this you can add the service dependency to `myHelperClass` using

```
def classifiedService
```

You can also inject the helper class into controllers and services.
If you need access to the helper class outside controllers/services you can get the instance using

```
def helper = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('myHelperClass')
```

See the [spring](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/spring.html) section in the Grails documentation for more details

Comment: There is no need to do the `bean.autowire='byName'` business.  That happens by default.  You can just do `myHelperClass(MyHelperClass)`.  Also, having the word "Class" be part of the bean name is a peculiar thing, but it would work.